# How can I recreate this roof inside Blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode, sculpting

Hey I am pretty new in Blender and I want to ask if somebody has an idea how I can recreate this roof?[image]

[Edit] It does now look like this how can I fill that gap? (Nvm I figured it out! :)
:
[image]

[Edit 2}] I don't want to show this part only on one side how can I do that? [image]

Here are some other referneces:
[image]
[image]

Comment: do you have another point of view of your house, large enough?

Comment: Yes but they are a little bit blurry.

Comment: First thing you should do is get better reference. If you can't see it you cannot understand the form, if you cannot understand the form, you cannot model it. I think it is very common cause for not being able to model something. I am quite confident with my modelling skills, but I can never model something that I cannot see well.

Comment: If you want the extruded shape on one side only, apply the Mirror modifier and delete the extrusion on the side you want. It would be good to have another point of view with good quality

Comment: I added some references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what the shape is but here is a try. First thing create the basic shape, use a *Mirror* modifier to symmetrize (enable its *Clipping* option):

[image]

Add some edges with the *Knife* tool, cut the parts that need to be cut:

[image]

Extrude these vertices on Y:

[image]

Extrude this part, flatten on Y with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, etc:

[image]